# Exe showing sensitive information when opening with a text document

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security

I recently discovered that my released programs written in C# using Visual Studios shows passwords and sql statements in plain text upon dragging the exe into a text document. The passwords are easy enough to encrypt but I have too many sql statements in too many different programs to easily go through and encrypt every one. How do I go about making the information in plain text to unreadable symbols?

Comment: @Joshua Might as well post that as an answer.

Comment: I understand its still possible to pull all the information, but the barrier to entry would be higher if it wasn't in plain text.

Strange that there's no way to compile it differently though.

Comment: with every program like `hexeditor`, `ollydbg`,`.Net Reflector`, and etc... every one can see your code clearly. maybe obfuscating code avoid a little to reading codes.

Comment: Why is it strange? It's always been like this. And not just .NET. In fact, Linux has a [strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) command that people have been using on native executables for decades.

Comment: @NicholasChowdhury: If somebody can't be bothered to do more than drag your file into a text editor they probably can't be bothered to find something naughty to do with that information. If they do want to do something bad to you then if all you do is protect against opening in a text editor then you have basically done nothing to protect yourself. The fact is that if the program is going to connect to a SQL server then it has to have the information to do so and if the program has that information then the user does too if they want.

Comment: As a small aside if you don't want SQL statements in your code you could use stored procedures instead. Then you just have a name and the SQL is hidden away on your server. I'm not sure what this problem actually solves apart from "I don't want them to see my SQL". If they can do bad things by knowing your SQL then they can probably do bad things without knowing it too.

Comment: What does the program do (broadly speaking)? It will help to know for constructive feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You do not protect secrets in the binary. Redesign with the assumption someone wanting to break in can access all secrets in the binary.

A long time ago we had this bad idea. We had protected the password from such trivial things as opening in a text editor. I gave a demonstration of obtaining the password in five minutes.

Today it has gotten easier. The reference sources for `System.Data.SqlClient` have been published and you can get a `.pdb` file for `System.Data.SqlClient`. Assume the guy wanting keys can do this.

There is a fundamental theorem of computer security: Remote attestation is impossible. You can only authenticate users, not programs.

There are things we can say that would slow down people who want to reverse engineer the software, and the second one is going to be "Don't use .NET."

Comment: I don't think .net is the issue. A properly architected solution built with security in mind from the get go would be.

Comment: @SteveJ: He is concerned about SQL statements. This is in the reverse engineering territory. I can't tell him to not worry about it. I can tell him it's too expensive, which I have.

Comment: Knowing more about what the program does would help I guess. Is it client/server. Does it talk to an API etc...

Comment: @Joshua How are .NET programs more problematic than native binaries in regards to exposing sensitive information?

Comment: @itsme86: They're not. Writing native code allows some steps to follow after that impose actual difficulty but would break .NET binaries.

Comment: @Joshua Can you give an example?

Comment: @itsme86: Encrypt almost entire binary, decrypt at startup to program RAM only.

Comment: But to decrypt you have to have the key somewhere, and if that key is accessible to the application, it must be accessible by a person as well. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @itsme86: You're not. These things only increase difficulty not make impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, it is not possible to hide information in a program as long as it needs to be able to decipher it by itself. You need to move the sensitive data and functionality elsewhere and provide your binary distribution with only the required privileges. E.g. it could store an API key to make authorized requests to a backend service.